# Arraylist of polynomial objects read from file only displaying last element

Tags: java

I am reading a file of polynomials using a JFileChooser and then parsing the file tokens into Strings, and then adding those Strings to an ArrayList of objects of type Polynomial. For example my .txt file looks like this: 12 1 3.6 2 9 8 which represents the polynomial "12x + 3.6x^2 + 9x^8" and on the second line I have 5.6 3 4 1 8.3 0 which represents the polynomial "5.6x^3 + 4x + 8.3"

I have to do a bunch of sorting stuff with them but what I need help with is printing out the ArrayList elements. For some reason, the ArrayLists are only displaying the last elements(terms) of each polynomial.
Here is the code in my main method and the logic looks sound to me but I'm hoping one of you more seasoned guys can point me in the right direction. Thank you!
The output is: **Polynomial1 : + 9.0x^8 Polynomial 2 : + 8.3** but my desired output is: **Polynomial 1: 12x + 3.6x^2 + 9.0x^8
Polynomial 2: 5.6x^3 + 4x + 8.3**

```
File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            s = r.readLine();
            while (s != null) {
                try {
                    num++;
                    // file correctly reads into String, but not printing out in toString method
                    // from
                    // Polynomial object
                    list.add(new Polynomial(s));
                    System.out.println("Polynomial " + num + " toString: " + "+ " + list.get(list.size() - 1));

                } catch (InvalidPolynomialSyntax e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter valid polynomial syntax", "Syntax Error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                s = r.readLine();

            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error encountered with input file, check file input and try again",
                    "IO Exception Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
    }
```

Comment: When you concatenate objects to strings with + the `Object::toString` method of the object is called. Thus it probably depends on what the `Polynomial::toString` override of this method does.

Comment: Thanks bro! You'r right it was something to do with my toSring method. I couldn't figure it out. Thank you!